# Console application doesn't print "Press any key to continue . . ."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I have third-party SDK code samples written in C++ (Console applications). When I run any of them from Visual Studio 2010 (Start without Debugging), it doesn't print  "Press any key to continue . . ." in the end, Console window is just closed.

How did they manage to get such behavior? More important: how can I get standard "Press any key to continue . . ." in the end? Of course, without changing the program code...

Comment: Why do you think you should get that message? Console applications are meant to be run from a command window and it would be counter-productive to show that message in an interactive session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the subsystem to Console in the link settings

Comment: that doesn't work :-( VS is dumb

Comment: I will accept the answer later when SO will allow this.

Comment: It not works for me too. :((( When I create new Console project, the "subsystem" already has `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`, but I not get the  "Press any key to continue..." message.

Answer (score 8):

Press Ctrl+F5 to run your program instead of just F5.

Comment: anyway to do this with the run button?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
system(PAUSE);
```

It should print what you are looking for